# calculating the width of ul by list items width display-block

Tags: javascript, css, spacing

Im practicing reusable coding so I decided to build a thumbnail scroller from scratch.

Im using display:inline-block on a set of list items with in a ul. to calculate the width of the ul I'm using .outerWidth(); I noticed a few fixes for the space display:inine-block puts in between elements however I am not sure which is the best solution.

The first fix I found was to add 2px to each elements width before calculating the width of the parent element.
The second fix I found was to add word-spacing: -2px; to the surrounding ul but this was off by about 1px.
The final fix seemed to be the best solution and this was to add font-size:0 to the parent and another font-size to the list items.

My curiosity is killing me and I need to know what is the best way to fix this and why font-size works.

Here is my jsfiddle for the project Im working on http://jsfiddle.net/SusannDelgado/wNvsx/

in the fiddle the lines below set the size

```
  var liw = parseInt($("#" + _globals.name + " > ul > li").outerWidth(true));
    _globals.innerwidth = ((liw) * _globals.count)
```

Comment: inline-boxes behaves just like words, ans a space in between appears. The size of that space relay on font-size and font used. Sized to zero, space (and letters) disappear :). Other solution in html code : make li touch each other (no space nor indented code) or insert an HTML comment to fill that space . If you minify HTML before to put it on line , space will be cured off (if you want this as your answer ... i'll do it )

Comment: Thank you :) it was driving me crazy not knowing this

Comment: You could put it as an answer but I understand you entirely

Comment: oki it could be usefull for others (unless it is already a duplicate). Cheers an good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inline-boxes behaves just like words, ans a space in between appears.

The size of that space relay on font-size and font used. Sized to zero, space (and letters) disappear :).

Other solution in html code : make li touch each other (no space nor indented code)
`<li>item</li><li>

 next-item</li><li>

  ....</li>`
 or insert an HTML comment to fill that space

```
<li>item</li><!--  
--><li>
```

. If you minify HTML before to put it on line , space will be cured off